# Unable to get google-appengine for Jruby to work

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, rubygems, jruby

I have been trying all day to get app-engine sdk to work nothing has really shaped up .

I emptied a gemset and installed `google-appengine` gem by executing

`sudo gem install google-appengine`

I have the following gems installed

```
[gdev@vbox-gdev GAE]$ sudo gem list
Password: 

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

appengine-apis (0.0.24)
appengine-rack (0.0.13)
appengine-sdk (1.4.3)
appengine-tools (0.0.17)
bundler08 (0.8.5)
google-appengine (0.0.21)
jruby-jars (1.5.6)
jruby-rack (1.0.4)
rack (1.3.5)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
[gdev@vbox-gdev GAE]$
```

and as mentioned in [this](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/wiki/GettingStarted) tutorial (http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/wiki/GettingStarted)
I am using CRuby instead of Jruby

```
[gdev@vbox-gdev GAE]$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]
```

I am getting an error in the first step itself

```
[gdev@vbox-gdev GAE]$ appcfg.rb generate_app hello
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
=> Generating gemfile
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/appengine-tools-0.0.17/lib/appengine-tools/gem_bundler.rb:63: warning: already initialized constant RUBY_ENGINE
=> Bundling gems
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command bundle
[gdev@vbox-gdev GAE]$
```

Installing `bundler`(either version 1.0.21 or 0.8)  throws the same error .

Any suggestions on solving this ?

PS: I am using arch linux on a virtualbox

Comment: "I am using CRuby instead of Jruby" - why do you expect this to work? You'll only be able to use Jruby on App Engine, so it's unlikely the library is tested on CRuby.

Comment: If you read http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/wiki/GettingStarted it is clearly mentioned to use standard ruby (Cruby) and not Jruby , which is why i was actually using it , I did try with jruby and it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should stick to Ruby 1.8.7.  1.9.x never really took off on appengine-jruby, although it's possible.  Moreover you should use Rubygems 1.3.7.

My local gems are these:

```
appengine-rack (0.0.13)
appengine-sdk (1.4.3)
appengine-tools (0.0.17)
bundler (1.0.21)
bundler08 (0.8.5)
google-appengine (0.0.21)
haml (3.1.4)
jruby-jars (1.5.6)
jruby-rack (1.0.4)
rack (1.4.0)
rubyzip (0.9.5)
sass (3.1.12)
```

But guess what, except for the google-appengine gem those aren't really important. Much much more important is this: `ls .gems/bundler_gems/jruby/1.8/gems`:

```
addressable-2.2.7              extlib-0.9.15        multipart-post-1.1.5
appengine-apis-0.0.22          faraday-0.7.6        oauth2-0.5.2
appengine-rack-0.0.12          haml-3.1.4           rack-1.2.1
Basaah-pony-gae-0.2.1          jruby-jars-1.5.6     rack-flash-0.1.2
bouncy-castle-java-1.5.0146.1  jruby-openssl-0.7.2  sass-3.1.15
dm-appengine-0.0.9             jruby-rack-1.0.5     sinatra-1.2.7
dm-core-0.10.2                 json_pure-1.6.5      tilt-1.3.3
dm-validations-0.10.2          multi_json-1.1.0
```

That at least will give you an easy start. (You can configure the version in the Gemfile)

By the way, good that you use Linux.

Answer (score 1):

hmm...for one, I'm not sure how you set up your jruby exactly, or which version of jruby you're running. You should be running jruby 1.5.5 on appengine from memory.

I strongly recommend following this guide: http://www.khelll.com/blog/ruby/google-app-engine-jruby-sinatra-and-some-fun/

After about 3 or 4 similar guides, this was the only configuration that worked for me.  I'm having some issues with ssl, but the app runs using the app engine gem and deploys to app engine successfully.