# Upload Jruby on rails on Google App Engine - cannot find gem appengine-rack

Tags: google-app-engine, rubygems, jrubyonrails

Just trying to deploy a simple Jruby on rails app on Google App Engine but falling at first hurdle.
I've been following instructions on https://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/ and a few other websites. I've installed the gem 'google-appengine' as instructed and Command Prompt tells me that it's installed.

As I started typing *require 'appengine-rack'* in my config.ru, I can see that my IDE tells me it doesn't recognise this file. I fire up the local server anyway just as a test and it tells me that "LoadError: no such file to load -- appengine-rack".

I can clearly see in C:\jruby-1.7.3\lib\ruby\gems\shared\gems\appengine-rack-0.0.13\lib\ . So I'm a bit stumped. When I run >gem list, I can also see that this gem is there.

I'm doing this for the first time.

I'm using Windows 7. Jruby version 1.7.3. Rails 3.2.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the [project](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/) you are trying to use is rather old, (last commit date is Date:     Mar 30, 2011). And it is written there that they are only planing to have a support of version 3.x.

Anyway here is the answer to your question(rather old too)
[Unable to get google-appengine for Jruby to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228735/unable-to-get-google-appengine-for-jruby-to-work)

And this search could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine+ruby

From rational point of view it is not very good idea to use this gems for production. If you need cloud hosting for your ruby procejct [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) would be a solution. 
If you require appengine - you better go Java, Python or Go which are officially supported.

Comment: Ah ok. Shame, I'm trying to learn Ruby at the moment and I quite like the idea of appengine... Thanks.

Comment: Last question about this problem was two years ago, so don't worry may be some one could find this useful.